# Pandas groupby and filtering groups with rows greater than N rows

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df of the following format

```
STOCK    YR    MONTH  DAY     PRICE
AAA     2022    1     1        10
AAA     2022    1     2        11
AAA     2022    1     3        10
AAA     2022    1     4        15
AAA     2022    1     5        10
BBB     2022    1     1        5
BBB     2022    1     2        10
BBB     2022    2     1        10
BBB     2022    2     2        15
```

What I am looking to do is to filter this `df` such that I am grouping by `STOCK` and `YR` and `MONTH` and selecting the `groups` with 3 or more entries.
So the resulting `df` looks like

```
STOCK    YR    MONTH  DAY     PRICE
AAA     2022    1     1        10
AAA     2022    1     2        11
AAA     2022    1     3        10
AAA     2022    1     4        15
AAA     2022    1     5        10
```

Note that `BBB` is eliminated as it had only 2 rows in each `group`, when grouped by `STOCK`, `YR` and `MONTH`

I have tried `df.groupby(['STOCK','YR','MONTH']).filter(lambda x: x.STOCK.nunique() > 5)` but this resulted in an `empty` frame.

Also tried `df.groupby(['STOCK','YR','MONTH']).filter(lambda x: x['STOCK','YR','MONTH'].nunique() > 5)` but this resulted in a `KeyError: ('STOCK', 'YR', 'MONTH')`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform('count')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df[df.groupby(['STOCK', 'YR', 'MONTH'])['STOCK'].transform('count').ge(3)]
```

or 'size':

```
df[df.groupby(['STOCK', 'YR', 'MONTH'])['STOCK'].transform('size').ge(3)]
```

output:

```
  STOCK    YR  MONTH  DAY  PRICE
0   AAA  2022      1    1     10
1   AAA  2022      1    2     11
2   AAA  2022      1    3     10
3   AAA  2022      1    4     15
4   AAA  2022      1    5     10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

If need counts (not exclude possible `NaN`s):

```
#if need test number of unique values
df[df.groupby(['STOCK', 'YR', 'MONTH'])['STOCK'].transform('size').gt(3)]
```

Or:

```
#in large df should be slow
df.groupby(['STOCK','YR','MONTH']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3)
```

Comment: your first solution is incorrect, 'nunique' will always give 1 as the tested value is necessarily unique in its group